# How to calculate column averages from csv file and write average rows into a new file using python

Tags: csv, average

Basically, I have a csv file being updated every 5 seconds. It adds a new row of data to it every 5 seconds. The file looks like this:

[image: Columns of data file]

I need to calculate averages for each column into a new row and write those row into a new averages file and keep appending to it.I don't have any headers for my columns file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide any evidence of coding attempts so that the community can better understand what you have already tried. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think people will be more inclined to help if you demonstrate that you've made an effort yourself.

To start you off, I'd suggest looking at the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) library. It includes the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) functions.

Because it's a bit hidden in the docs- you can tell Pandas to add rows to the end of an existing csv by setting the Python write mode in the to_csv function:

```
df.to_csv('averages.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Hit me up if you have any more questions!